# Cannot get hold of cannonical statements on my code, php niewbie here

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I want to get a post content from a MySQL DB, using the post name ($post variable that comes from URL of the page). it is working OK with the normal statements, but my tries to secure it from SQL injections fail miserably. Since it's my first try on canonical statements, I cannot find the cause of failure.
On the code below, the commented out part is the one that actually works and brings results.

```
<?php {
$post = htmlspecialchars($_GET["post"]);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT postcontent FROM posts WHERE postCN = ? ");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $post);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
//$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT postcontent FROM posts WHERE postCN='$post'");
//$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
//if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
  echo $row['postcontent']; ?>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo $siteurl ?>" role="button">Exit</a>
  <?php }
else {
  echo "there is no such post" ;
  header( "refresh:2; $siteurl" );
}
$stmt->close();
}?>
```

EDIT: Fail definition: I don't get a blank page (meaning that probably its not a typo error), but I still don't get result. either the post content or the "there is no such post" echo. connection to the DB is working, since the commented out part gives results

Comment: define *fail* please

Comment: Fail: I don't get a blank page (meaning that probably its not a typo error), but I still don't get result. either the post content or the "there is no such post" echo. connection to the DB is working, since the commented out part gives results

Comment: You are **always** getting the *"there is no such post"* message ?

Comment: Did you `$mysqli = new mysqli("server", "user", "password", "db");` ?

Comment: $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>


thats how i used to connect to db.

Comment: `$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT postcontent FROM posts WHERE postCN = ? ");` <--- use `$conn` instead of `$mysqli`

Comment: youre correct. as i get it the connection name on my connection should be $mysqli OR the above code should have $conn instead of $mysqli.

this worked as charm

Answer (score -1):

As `@CID` mentioned my mistake is that I changed the connection name from `$conn` to `$mysqli`

The correct statement is :

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT postcontent FROM posts WHERE postCN = ? ");
```